# Void in java for new beginners (help)

Tags: java, void

Hi I know for fact `void` means "no return values"
But my comprehension is terrible, I just want to know how to use `void` I mean when to use ,please I am just a beginner, help me.

Comment: What answer are you looking for other than "You use it when you don't want to return a value"?

Comment: Sorry: SO is **not** programming school where people **explain** elementary concepts to you. Thats like so basic ... as sepp2k says; what kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: I'm baffled by how people would rather ask something online and wait for the answer than just grab a book or tutorial.

Comment: @MaciejDziuban Spend another two months here; and you will be baffled about people like you, how are buffled about newbies asking such questions ;-)

Comment: `void` methods don't return values an therefore can't be part of an assignment. For example you cant say `Object o = System.out.println()` and lets leave aside functional programming since it's clearly out of scope here.

Comment: @GhostCat That may just be too many layers of bafflement for me :D

Comment: @MaciejDziuban Spend another 12 months here; then no number of layers will baffle you.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, let's go about this with an example, 'cuz those are awesome!

The `void` keyword implies that a function doesn't return any value.

So let's take two function examples here:

```
void printWhoa() {
    System.out.println("Whoa!");
}
```

In the above example, the function clearly states that it doesn't return any value, hence the *void* in the function/method declaration.

Here's an example where it does!

```
int returnNumMultipliedByTwo(int num) {
     return num*2;
}
```

Here, the method says it returns an *int* and it does! And we can use that elsewhere! :)

Write some code, get the hang of it. Don't just read books, you'll understand all of it!

Hope this helps!